# FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't update items

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have FragmentPager Adapter which looks like this :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private List<ImageItem> items;

    public ImageAdapter(List<ImageItem> items, FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        fragment.setItem(items.get(position));
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        ImageFragment fragment = (ImageFragment)object;
        int position = items.indexOf(fragment.getItem());

        if(position >= 0) {
            fragment.pudDataChanges();
            return position;
        } else return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

So fragment by itself is empty, all customization comes in getItem and getItemsPoisition, then i have a loader which creates this adapter ant puts it to ViewPager:

```
 @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<ImageItem>> loader, ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(data, getChildFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        hideProgressDialog();

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(SearchHelper.INSERT_ITEMS_TO_DATABASE_ID, null, new InsertItemsToDatabaseHandler(data)).forceLoad();

    }
```

The first time it sets everything is ok, but second time and later times it just doesn't call getItem() and i have empty Fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add

```
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<ImageItem>> loader) {
    pager.setAdapter(null);
}
```

to the class that implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<>`.